# EC cardinality $P^3+c$ with 3 gen $G$, $F = P\cdot G,H=P^2\cdot G$ and 2 random members $M_1+iG+jF+kH=M_2$. How long would it take to find $i,j,k$?

Tags: elliptic-curves, security-definition

Given a EC with cardinality $C=P^3+c$ with $P$ a prime $P \approx \sqrt[3]{C}$ and $c>0$.
Out of a given generator $G$ we generate two additional generator $F,H$ with
$$F = P \cdot G$$
$$H = P^2 \cdot G$$

(all would still generate a sequence of length $P^3+c$)
Given now a random member $M_1$ of that EC we can generate a $P\times P \times P$ cube of different members with
$$ M_1 +i\cdot G+j\cdot F+k\cdot H = V_{M_1ijk}$$
$$ i,j,k \in [0,P-1]$$
$$|\{V_{M_1ijk}\}| = P^3$$

Every other random member $M_2$ can be produced out of $M_1$ with:
$$M_2 = M_1+i\cdot G+j\cdot F+k\cdot H $$
$$ i,j,k \in [0,P]$$

---

**Question:**
Given now two random members $M_1,M_2 $ how many steps are needed to find the related $i,j,k$ (on average time)? How would that work?
Would it be (much) safer if we pick $P = 2\cdot p+1$ with $p$ a prime?
Would it be (much) safer if we pick three (secret) prime factors $P_1,P_2,P_3$ instead? with $P_1 \cdot P_2 \cdot P_3 \approx C$

(I'm looking for rough estimates related to $C,P$ in ($O$-notation). We can e.g. ignore the different bit-length-related impact at 2 number multiplication )

---

*The adversary* does know about the used EC, the generators $G,F,H$ and their inverses $G^{-1},F^{-1},H^{-1}$, the random members $M_1,M_2$ and the internal structure. He does not know about $P,d$ but as there are not too many options we assume he does know this as well. 
He want to find unknown $i,j,k$ for random known $M_1,M_2$.

---

*Side-question:* Are there any restrictions of safe EC which can be used for this? E.g.
would M-221 with $y^2 = x^3+117050x^2+x$ $\bmod p = 2^{221} - 3$ work for this?

---

*Trial:*
If we just have a single generator $G$ it should take $O(\sqrt{C})$ using baby-step-giant-step. If $P$ is known $i,j,k$ can be constructed out of this.
With $F,H$ we could do a surface around $M_1$ and a straight line with $G$ at $M_2$ until an intersection of those. This would take $O(P^2+P)\rightarrow O(P^2)$ which would be larger than $O(\sqrt{C})=O(P\sqrt{P})$. So $F,H$ no help here.
Could those generators $F,H$ help to make it somehow faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given now two random members $M_1, M_2$ how many steps are needed to find the related $i,j,k$ (on average time)?

The problem of finding $i, j, k$ is equivalent to the discrete log problem:

- If you can solve the discrete log problem, you can compute $i, j, k$ (by computing the discrete log of $M_2 - M_1$, and then expressing that discrete log in base $P$)
- If you can compute $i, j, k$, you can solve the discrete log problem (to compute the discrete log of a point M, you would pick an arbitrary point $M_1$, set $M_2 = M + M_1$, compute $i, j, k$; then, the discrete log of $M$ is $i + jP + kP^2$

For a curve with no known weaknesses, computing the discrete log is believed to take $O(\sqrt{C})$ time; if you select a curve with known weaknesses (e.g. a pairing friendly curve that has a pairing operation into a finite field where the discrete log is easier), then the time to solve your problem also drops accordingly.